# Pass Selected Values to a Get request

Tags: reactjs, csv, formik

My goal is to pass values selected in a form, to a `get` request.

The request should look as follows, following `submit` of the `values`.

`get(api/csv/pets/?columns=DOG&columns=CAT&columns=FISH)`

```
onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    setCsvData(values);
    console.log(csvData);  
    const getCsvFile = async (values) => {
      try {
        const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
          `/api/csv/pets/${id}/?columns=${csvData ? csvData + '&' : null}`, values);
    
        toCsv(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getCsvFile();
```

However, even though formik takes a payload of values, I still get undefined when placing it in `csvData` with `setCsvData(values)`.

What can I do to get the values selected in the query, and in the format needed?

My data:

```
export const CheckList = [
  {
    id: 'column-dog',
    label: 'Dog',
    value: 'DOG',
    name: 'column',
  },
  {
    id: 'column-cat',
    label: 'Cat',
    value: 'CAT',
    name: 'column',
  },
  {
    id: 'column-turtle',
    label: 'Turtle',
    value: 'TURTLE',
    name: 'column',
  },
  {
    id: 'column-fish',
    label: 'Fish',
    value: 'FISH',
    name: 'column',
  },
]
```

My Form:

[image]

```
const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState([]);
const selectAllData = CheckList.map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);


return (
     <Formik
        initialValues={{
           columns: [],
           selectAll: false,
        }}
        onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          setCsvData(values);
          console.log(csvData);
          resetForm();
        }}
        >
         {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
           <Form>
            <div>
              <Field
                onChange={() => {
                  if (!values.selectAll) {
                    setFieldValue('columns', selectAllData);
                  } else {
                    setFieldValue('columns', []);
                  }
                  setFieldValue('selectAll', !values.selectAll);
                }}
                checked={values.selectAll}
                type="checkbox"
                name="selectAll"
              />{' '}
              Select All
            </div>
    
          {CheckList.map((checkbox) => (
            <div key={checkbox.value}>
              <label>
                <Field
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="columns"
                  value={checkbox.value}
                 />{' '}
                 {checkbox.label}
               </label>
             </div>
           ))}
    
          <button
            className="btn"
            type="submit"
            download
          >
            DOWNLOAD CSV
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've over-complicated your code a little bit. Remove `csvData` from state, and instead pass `values` into request.

```
onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
    const getCsvFile = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
          `/api/csv/pets/${id}/?columns=${values ? values + '&' : null}`, values);
        toCsv(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getCsvFile();
}
```

You were getting an error is because the request was firing before `csvData` was set. `setState` is asynchronous :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use setState inside an async function, becuase setState is an async function itself and it doesn't return a promise. As a result, we can't use `async/await` for **setState** method.(If it's not possible to make it `await`, then state change will trigger right away with `undefined` values instead of setting the given values)

Please refer this for more info: https://iamsongcho.medium.com/is-setstate-async-b1947fbb25e5

Therefore, the best use case is to remove the `async` from `onSubmit()` function to make it synchronous. As a result, setState will trigger the state change in component asynchronously.

Then keep `getCsvFile(values)`, after form reset as you've already done that. And keep `getCsvFile()` function outside the component, since it doesn't do any state relevant changes.

```
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setCsvData(values);
        console.log(csvData);
        resetForm();

        getCsvFile(); // this function will trigger asynchronously
      }}
```